# How to display array in label?

Tags: arrays, swift, label

How can I print array, containing from struct values in the label?

I can only print them in console. I need to display some currencies to USD when clicking on the button.

```
struct myCurrency {

var currency: String
var currentPrice: String


func showCurrencies() {

print("\(currency) to \(currentPrice)")


}

}

@IBAction func showCurrencies(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let btc = myCurrency(currency: "BTC", currentPrice: "10223.4337")

    let gbp = myCurrency(currency: "GBP", currentPrice: "1,2221")

    let rub = myCurrency(currency: "RUB", currentPrice: "0.015169")

    let eur = myCurrency(currency: "EUR", currentPrice: "1.11")

    let uah = myCurrency(currency: "UAH", currentPrice: "0.039841")


    let curArray = [btc.showCurrencies(), gbp.showCurrencies(), rub.showCurrencies(),eur.showCurrencies(),uah.showCurrencies()]

    label.text = curArray // here's error 
   //Cannot assign value of type '[()]' to type 'String?'
```

Comment: Show the kind of output you need to display in the label.

Comment: Do you want them 1 on each row?

Comment: @PGDev I need to display this in the label. 

"BTC to 10223.4337
GBP to 1,2221
RUB to 0.015169
EUR to 1.11
UAH to 0.039841"

Comment: `curArray.forEach({ (item) in
                string += "\(item.currency) to \(item.currentPrice) \n"
            })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform `MyCurrency` to `CustomStringConvertible` and override its `description` property to `return` the required `String` instance,

```
struct MyCurrency: CustomStringConvertible {

    var currency: String
    var currentPrice: String

    var description: String {
        return "\(currency) to \(currentPrice)"
    }
}
```

Now, to get a `String` of currencies, use **`map(_:)`** and **`joined()`** on the `array` of `MyCurrency`, i.e.

```
let btc = MyCurrency(currency: "BTC", currentPrice: "10223.4337")
let gbp = MyCurrency(currency: "GBP", currentPrice: "1,2221")
let rub = MyCurrency(currency: "RUB", currentPrice: "0.015169")
let eur = MyCurrency(currency: "EUR", currentPrice: "1.11")
let uah = MyCurrency(currency: "UAH", currentPrice: "0.039841")

let str = [btc, gbp, rub, eur, uah].map({ String(describing: $0) }).joined()
print(str) //BTC to 10223.4337GBP to 1,2221RUB to 0.015169EUR to 1.11UAH to 0.039841
label.text = str
```

**Update:**

You can use **`reduce(_:_:)`** as well to get the required output, i.e.

```
let str = [btc, gbp, rub, eur, uah].reduce("") { (result, currency) -> String in
    return result + String(describing: currency)
}
print(str) //BTC to 10223.4337GBP to 1,2221RUB to 0.015169EUR to 1.11UAH to 0.039841
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works! Can you please explain this line of code? 

let str = [btc, gbp, rub, eur, uah].map({ String(describing: $0) }).joined()

Comment: `map` converts the array of currencies to an array of String and then `joined()` combined all the Strings in the array with an empty String. You can `reduce` as well to get the similar response. I updated the answer with how you can use `reduce`.